# como puedo retornar al menu de un NavigationView en android studio?

Tags: java, android, eventos

que tal quiero regresar a las demas opciones del menu estoy usando un NavigationView este es el codigo espero y puedan ayudarme estoy comenzando en esto de las app

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
       /* int opcion=item.getOrder();
        switch (opcion){

            case 0:
                setContentView(R.layout.diezxmexico);*/

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.menu_vista1:

                setContentView(R.layout.diezxmexico);


                return true;

        }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    menu_visible = true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con base en los comentarios, lo que pides es un [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView), lo que podrías hacer es añadir una etiqueta `NavigationView` en el Activity_main.xml con un [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout), el root del XML sería un [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout).

El resultado quedaría tal que así:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"/>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

También tendrás que crear el XML del menú, lo puedes crear en el directorio `Res.menu` con `click derecho > new > menu resource file`.
En este XML pondrás las los 'Items' que representan los fragmens a los que el usuario puede acceder.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_leyendo"
            android:title="Leyendo" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_biblioteca"
            android:title="Biblioteca" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_papelera"
            android:title="Papelera" />

</menu>
```

Así ya tendríamos el cómo se ve el menú, pero antes de implementarlo es necesario aclarar el tema de los  fragments. Por cada `item` tendremos un fragmen que recordemos que son secciones modulares de la interfaz de usuario dentro de un `Activity`. Cada `Fragment` necesita su propio .java y .xml. Además de necesitar la extensión `Fragment`.
Para este ejemplo te voy a poner como podrías crear uno manualmente, pero también puedes crearlos más fácilmente con `new > fragment`.

```java
public class Biblioteca extends Fragment {

    public Biblioteca() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.biblioteca_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

}
```

Una vez creado el menú y los fragments necesarios ya podemos implementarlos en el Main para crear nuestro ansiado menú.
Para esto necesitaremos implementar él `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    //menu
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


    //declaracion de fragmentos y transacion
    //despues se definiran con su respectiva clase para la navegacion
    //fragmentLeyendo == Fragmento inicial
    FragmentTransaction transactioni;
    Fragment fragmentLeyendo, fragmentBiblioteca, fragmentPapelera;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instancia de diseño de cajón para alternar el icono de menú para abrir
        //Cajón y botón de retroceso para cerrar el cajón
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

        //Pase el botón de alternancia Abrir y Cerrar para el detector de diseño de cajón
        //Para alternar el botón
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // para que el icono del cajón de navegación aparezca siempre en la barra de acciones
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView navigationView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Creacion de objetos fragment y transaction
        //esto despues se carga en el metedo onNavigationItemSelect para el cambio de dicho fragmento
        fragmentLeyendo = new Leyendo();
        fragmentBiblioteca = new Biblioteca();
        fragmentPapelera = new Papelera();

// de esta forma al iniciar el programa entrara en el fragmen leyendo
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout,fragmentLeyendo).commit();

    }

    // Cierra el menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // se ejecuta cuando el usuario selecciona un item del menu
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        gestorTransiciones(item.getItemId());
        return false;
    }

    //realiza la transicion entre fragmentos
    public void gestorTransiciones(int id){
        transactioni = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.nav_leyendo:
                transactioni.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragmentLeyendo).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_biblioteca:
                transactioni.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragmentBiblioteca).commit();;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_papelera:
                transactioni.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragmentPapelera).commit();
                break;
        }
        // cierra el menu despues de la transicion
        this.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
```

También si quieres actualizar los datos del fragment después de utilizar `finish()` puedes implementar el siguiente método en el fragment:

```java
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // aqui introduces el codigo necesario para obtener los datos
    // como llamar a la base de datos o acceder a un archivo
    // depende de como gestiones tus archivos
}
```

Tienes la aplicación que he desarrollado para probar este código en el siguiente repositorio de GitHub:

- https://github.com/Jibuza/android-crear-menu

Comment: @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Implementa un boton en el toolbar para retroceder OPCIONAL

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
esa linea de codigo si la tengo pero no me sale esa flecha cuando entro en el primer caso del switch entnces quiero ocupar la "hamburguesa" para que nuevamente abra el menu vi que con el ActionBarDrawerToggle hace eso pero no se si deba de hacer algo con el navigationview

Comment: Vale... Lo que se podría hacer es crear un menú en el Activity principal y cada vez que el usuario quiera navegar por el menú se abrirá el menú(Activity) y al ser seleccionado modificara el (fragment). Voy a modificar la respuesta para que se adecue a lo que me acabas de contestar.

Comment: excelente explicacion lo probare te agradezco bastante , probe de nuevo el codigo anterior y salio la flecha no se como pero funciono XD